# Rewrite part of url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

There are so many examples on Stack, but I can't get this working for my site.

I need to rewrite this

```
http://www.example.com/folder/nicelooking-page/page/4
```

to this

```
http://www.example.com/folder/nice/page/4
```

I thought this would work, but it didn't

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/nicelooking-page/(.*)$ /folder/nice/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Without any kind of rewriting is http://www.example.com/folder/nice/page/4 accessable?

Comment: Just tested it and yes it exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?folder/nicelooking-page/page/(.*)$ /folder/nice/page/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

You had `page` missing in rewrite rule.

Comment: Almost there! For some reason it adds another dir in front of the url and now I get 
     http://www.example.com/dir/folder/nice/page/4

Comment: Is your htacces rule inside project root directory or inside another directory?

Comment: Please take a look now. I have added slash in front of replacement url. Now that url  will be appended after site host.

Comment: It is in the root and I have also tried in the other directory, but both have the same result.
It's a Wordpress site and I have moved it to it's own directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43204/discussion-between-chanchal118-and-wendit)

Comment: Terrible! I just removed the rule from htaccess and saw that it was still rewriting the url. Then I emptied the cache and it worked. So sorry for wasting your time. The above answer was already perfect! Thanks